# What is the junction of a closed string crossing over itself called? What is the name of the number describing the probability that the string changes

Tags: string-theory

There was a lecture by Leonard Susskind I came across some time ago. I am searching for the terms he used to describe the unknot like crossing of closed string over itself such that given the lemniscate like figure a probability is defined at it’s junction. If I remember correctly this was generalizable to the crossings of strings in general. Crossings finds me lots of work on knot theory, and not so much for the former. Your insight would be appreciated.

Comment: ‘self intersection’

Comment: Thank you, kind interloper. It was driving me down.